# What is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{F_i}{i}$?

Tags: summation, closed-form, fibonacci-numbers

Mathematica is [able](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BFibonacci%5Bi%5D%2Fi,%7Bi,1,n%7D%5D) to evaluate the summation $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{F_i}{i}$ in terms of the [Lerch transcendent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html). It is natural to consider whether or not this summation can be expressed in a more simple way.

It is conceivable that it is possible that $a_{n} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{F_i}{i}$ may be expressed in a more compact way, perhaps in terms of Fibonacci and Lucas numbers somehow, using the nearest integer function or the floor function.

Integer sequences such as $(\lfloor a_{n} \rfloor)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, $([a_{n}])_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, $( n! a_{n}  )_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, and $( \text{den}(a_{n})  )_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are not currently in the [On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/).

It appears that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln a_{n}}{n} \approx 0.481$ converges to a constant.  What is this constant? Can this constant be used to somehow express the sequence $(a_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in closed form?

Comment: Since $F_i$ is of the form $c(a^i-b^i)$, you can write $a_n$ as the difference of two truncated logarithmic series.

Comment: I don't know if it can be useful, but $$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{F_{n}}{n}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{z^{N+1}F_{N}+z^{N}F_{N+1}-1}{z^{2}+z-1}dz$$ and maybe using the Binet formula it is possible to find something.

Comment: I edited my answer with a more precise expansion that may be of interest too,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EXPANDED**: 
Let's define :
$$\tag{1}a_n(x):=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{F_k}{k}x^k$$
and use $\,F_k=\dfrac {\varphi^{\,k}-\psi^{,k}}{\sqrt{5}}\;$ with $\;\varphi=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}2,\ \psi=\dfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}2=-\dfrac 1{\varphi}\;$ (as suggested by Aravind and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression)) then :

\begin{align}
a_n(x)&=\frac 1{\sqrt{5}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\varphi^{\,k}-\psi^{,k}\right)\frac{x^k}k\tag{2}\\
&=\frac 1{\sqrt{5}} \int\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\varphi^{\,k}-\psi^{,k}\right) \frac {x^{k}}x\,dx\\
&=\frac 1{\sqrt{5}}\left(\int \frac{(\varphi\,x)^{\,n}-1}{\varphi\,x-1}\varphi\,dx-\int\frac{(\psi\,x)^{\,n}-1}{\psi\,x-1}\psi\,dx\right)\\
&=\frac 1{\sqrt{5}}\int_{\psi\,x}^{\varphi\,x} \frac{u^{\,n}-1}{u-1}\,du=\frac 1{\sqrt{5}}\int_{\psi\,x}^{\varphi\,x}\ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\;u^{\,k}\,du\tag{3}\\
&\quad\text{writing the integrand at the left as a sum of two terms gives :}\\\\
a_n:=a_n(1)&=\frac 1{\sqrt{5}}\left(-B_{\varphi}(n+1,0)+B_{\psi}(n+1,0)-\log(1-\varphi)+\log(1-\psi)\right)\tag{4}\\
\end{align}
with $B_x(a,b)$ the [incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) (the singularities in the integrals are removable and will not be considered).

All this is probably not very useful for practical evaluations but $(2)$ applied to $x=1$ allows to find a closed form for your limit $\;\displaystyle l:=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln a_{n}}{n}$ using $\varphi>1$ and $|\psi|<1$ :
\begin{align}
a_n&=\frac 1{\sqrt{5}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}k\left(\varphi^{\,k}-\psi^{,k}\right)\\
a_n&\sim \frac 1{\sqrt{5}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\varphi^{\,k}}k,\quad n\to\infty\\
&\sim \frac 1{\sqrt{5}}\frac{\varphi^{\,n}}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\varphi^{\,k-n}\;n}k,\quad n\to\infty\\
&\quad\text{setting $\;j:=n-k\,$ gives}\\
&\sim \frac 1{\sqrt{5}}\frac{\varphi^{\,n}}{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac 1{\varphi^{\,j}\;\frac {n-j}n},\quad n\to\infty\\
&\sim \frac 1{\sqrt{5}}\frac{\varphi^{\,n}}{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac {1+\sum_{m>0} \left(\frac jn\right)^m}{\varphi^{\,j}},\quad n\to\infty\\
&\sim \frac 1{\sqrt{5}}\frac{\varphi^{\,n}}{n}\left(\frac 1{1-\frac 1{\varphi}}+\sum_{m>0}\frac 1{n^m}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac {j^m}{\varphi^{\,j}}\right) ,\quad n\to\infty\\
&\sim \frac 1{\sqrt{5}}\frac{\varphi^{\,n}}{n}\left(\frac {\varphi}{\varphi-1}+\sum_{m>0}\frac {\Phi\left(\frac 1{\varphi},-m,0\right)}{n^m}\right) ,\quad n\to\infty\tag{5}\\
a_n&\sim \frac{\varphi^{\,n+1}}{\sqrt{5}\;n\,(\varphi-1)},\quad n\to\infty\tag{6}\\
\end{align}
With $\Phi$ the [Lerch transcendent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function#Definition) $\;\displaystyle\Phi(z,s,a):=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{z^n}{(n+a)^s}$.

The limit will simply be :
$$l=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln a_{n}}{n}=\log(\varphi)=\log\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}2\approx 0.4812118251$$
$$-$$
Let's use $(5)$ to get a more precise expansion defining $\;\displaystyle f_m(z):=\sum_{n\ge 0}n^m\,z^n=\Phi(z,-m,0)$.

For $m$ a nonnegative integer we have $\;\displaystyle f_{m+1}(z)=z\,f_{m}(z)'=z\sum_{n\ge 0}n^m\,n\,z^{n-1}=\sum_{n\ge 0}n^{m+1}\,z^{n}\ $
giving us the closed forms :
\begin{align}
f_0(z)&=\frac 1{(1-z)}\\
f_1(z)&=\frac z{(1-z)^2}\\
f_2(z)&=\frac {z^2+z}{(1-z)^3}\\
f_3(z)&=\frac {z^3+4z^2+z}{(1-z)^4}\\
\cdots
\end{align}
Using $\;z:=\dfrac 1{\varphi}\;$ so that $\,\dfrac 1{1-z}=\dfrac {\varphi}{\varphi-1}\;$ we may rewrite $(5)$ as :

\begin{align}
a_n&\sim \frac 1{\sqrt{5}}\frac{\varphi^{\,n}}{n}\left(\frac {\varphi}{\varphi-1}+\frac {\varphi}{(\varphi-1)^2\,n}+\frac {\varphi+\varphi^2}{(\varphi-1)^3\,n^2}+\frac {\varphi+4\varphi^2+\varphi^3}{(\varphi-1)^4\,n^3}+\cdots\right) \\
a_n&\sim \frac 1{\sqrt{5}}\frac{\varphi^{\,n}}{n}\left(\varphi+1+\frac {2\varphi+1}{n}+\frac {8\varphi+5}{n^2}+\frac {50\varphi+31}{n^3}+\frac{416\varphi+257}{n^4}+\cdots\right) \\
\end{align}

The sequences of integers appearing there are known : OEIS [A000557](https://oeis.org/A000557) and [A000556](https://oeis.org/A000556) allowing us to write this exponential generating function :
\begin{align}
\frac{\varphi+e^{-x}}{1-2\sinh(x)}&=(\varphi+1)+(2\varphi+1)\frac x{1!}+(8\varphi+5)\frac {x^2}{2!}+(50\varphi+31)\frac {x^3}{3!}+(416\varphi+257)\frac {x^4}{4!}+\cdots\\
\end{align}

The OEIS links should help you to find further relations and interesting links.

Comment: A more precise expansion would be : $$a_n\sim \frac{\varphi^{\,n+1}}{\sqrt{5}n\,(\varphi-1)}\left(1+\frac {\varphi}n+\frac{\varphi^4}{n^2}\right)$$